# Установка загрузчика Linux

Tags: linux

Что выбрать на пункте: "Установка загрузчика", стоит еще Windows 7.

1. Жесткий диск.
2. C раздела Linux.
3. Не устанавливать.

Устанавливаю в первый раз, помогите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашему предыдущему вопросу вы пробуете установить (или переустановить) Ubuntu, и вас спрашивают, куда поместить загрузчик grub. Вы вполне можете выбрать опцию - с раздела Linux.